# Running and Contributing Hadoop Scheduler algorithm

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, scheduler, simulator

I am actively looking for a way to contribute in hadoop development. I want to run an user-defined scheduling algorithm in hadoop cluster and want to see its performance. I have already configured hadoop cluster and have gone through Yarn Scheduler Load Simulator (SLS). Now, for executing other user-defined algorithms and check their performances respect to regular schedulers (Fair/Capacity), what procedures/steps I need to follow? Which one will be better, simulator or regular cluster? I am noob in hadoop and badly need help for this.